# Flutter Twitter Login Stopped Working With Authentication Error 'Sorry, that page doesn't exist' (code 34)

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, twitter, twitter-login

So the situation is as follows, I used 3 different packages from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) all for the purpose of user authentication with Twitter [(3-legged Oauth)](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens). My main package which I was using in my app was [flutter_twitter_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter_login). This worked flawlessly until today when I run my app everything was still working (launched the sign in page and signed in successfully) until the authorisation function was triggered when then I was redirected to the 'Sorry, that page doesn't exist' page with a search bar on Twitter (error code 34). I thought maybe this is a problem with my package like a new bad update, simply not the case, all 3 most known packages for user authentication failed in the exact same way. The other 2 I tested were [twitter_login](https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_login) and [flutter_twitter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter).

Keep in mind that 2 days ago I had a successful login within my app with a confirmation message and valid HTTP message returned. Most of my code were examples given by the flutter package creators.

**I made no changes to my code, yet it broke seemingly on its own**

After seeing some relevant problems over the years reported on stack overflow and the Twitter developer forums I suspect that the problem may be with the API endpoints (which my flutter packages manipulate, not me). Any opinions/directions?

PS: I have seen issues that say about the app becoming deactivated, disabling 3-legged Oauth by accident and account getting blocked all 3 of these are not the issue I checked/tested thoroughly.

Relevant Twitter forums post: https://twittercommunity.com/t/flutter-twitter-login-stopped-working-with-authentication-error-sorry-that-page-doesnt-exist-code-34/152435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that **the issue was on the API side** and it has been **resolved without me changing anything to my code**. The issue lasted 48 hours.